# Use python to add two timecodes together

Tags: python, video, timecodes

I am extracting timecode from video files and need to add the two together to get a total running time.
So I have one video that is 00:20:10:01 and another video that is 00:14:15:05, and want to get the value 00:34:25:06, the sum of both.
Lets say the timecode is at 23.98, and is a string.
What would be the calculation?

Comment: what is the timecodes type (`str`, `int`, `timedelta`)?

Comment: You also have to consider the framerate of the video to make the calculation. For example, in PAL its framerate is 25 FPS, whenever the frames add 25, those will add a second. On the other hand if it NTSC it would be 29.97 FPS and a long term adjustment must be done while adding timecodes.

Comment: I have updated the question, lets say the frame rate is 23.98, and the timecode is a string.

Comment: Maybe the use of a library like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timecode/0.3.0 could help.